# Is there any way to make C# application properties persist through recompiles?

Tags: c#, properties

The system for saving/reloading values is convenient but it has one annoying gotcha for a developer:  The ID changes on every recompile and thus it's basically useless in development.  Are there any easy fixes to this?  Google only tells me others have the same annoyance so I doubt there's anything other than doing it myself.

Edit: David Yew is right about the file.

Comment: Damn you Google (shakes fist angrily towards the ceiling)!

Comment: Which ID are you talking about?

Comment: I think he's referring to the default settings file, which gets written to `Documents and Settings\<user>\Local Settings\Application Data\<companyName>\<exename>_<someHashCode>\<exeVersion>\user.config`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the version of your exe in the properties of the project?  If you set this to something other than 0.0.0.0 I think it will maintain the settings for you.

Comment: The version already is 1.0.0.0.  The problem is the hash code changes each time and thus it gets a new name.